# XML to Google Map Markers

Tags: xml, apache, google-maps, http, csv

I am using `Xampp Apache Server` for this project. Basically the project is turn the CSV into an XML document using `XMLHttpRequest` to loop through the XML document, extract the attributes(such as: lat, long, and etc...) for each location and then create a map point marker.

Below is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
  xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

  <title>Read XML Files with Google Maps</title>
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps? file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAA7_kD1t_m22HBF9feCaDPZxQwcATY4FXmxYwkk9LNWGtAQdNKTBS1kBsTEqrRPg2kWxuNdmf2JVCIkQ" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="markermanager.js"></script>

<script>
   var map;

   function initialize () {  
   if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
     map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
     map.setCenter(new GLatLng(30.279, -97.700), 13);  
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
     map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
     map.addMapType(G_PHYSICAL_MAP);
  map.setMapType(G_PHYSICAL_MAP);

 addMarkersFromXML();

   }

   }

    function addMarkersFromXML(){
   var batch = [];
   mgr = new MarkerManager(map); 

   var request = GXmlHttp.create();
   request.open('GET', 'Landmarks.xml', true);
   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
  var xmlDoc = request.responseXML;
  var xmlrows = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("Row");

  for (var i = 0; i < xmlrows.length; i++) {
    var xmlrow = xmlrows[i];

     var xmlcellLongitude = xmlrow.getElementsByTagName("Longitude")[0];
     var xmlcellLatitude = xmlrow.getElementsByTagName("Latitude")[0];
     var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(xmlcellLatitude.firstChild.data),      parseFloat(xmlcellLongitude.firstChild.data));

  //get the building name
  var xmlcellBuildingName = xmlrow.getElementsByTagName("Building_Name")[0];
  var celltextBuildingName = xmlcellBuildingName.firstChild.data;

  //get the address
  var xmlcellAddress = xmlrow.getElementsByTagName("Address")[0];
  var celltextAddress = xmlcellAddress.firstChild.data;

  //get the ownership
  var xmlcellOwnership = xmlrow.getElementsByTagName("Ownership")[0];
  var celltextOwnership = xmlcellOwnership.firstChild.data;

  //get the date built
  var xmlcellDateBuilt = xmlrow.getElementsByTagName("Date_Built")[0];
  var celltextDateBuilt = xmlcellDateBuilt.firstChild.data;

  var htmlString = "Building Name: " + celltextBuildingName + "<br>" + "Address: " + celltextAddress + "<br>" + "Ownership: " + celltextOwnership + "<br>" + "Date Built: " + celltextDateBuilt;
  //var htmlString = 'yes'
  var marker = createMarker(point,htmlString);
  batch.push(marker);

}

mgr.addMarkers(batch,13);
mgr.refresh();

  }
    }
 request.send(null);

   }

  function createMarker(point,html) {
       var marker = new GMarker(point);
       GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
         marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
       });
       return marker;
 }

  </script>
 </head>
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
   <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1350px; height: 800px"></div>
   <div id="message"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And XML File:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <Row>
            <Longitude>-97.772588</Longitude>
           <Latitude>30.249405</Latitude>
      <Building_Name>GOODRICH BAPTIST CHURCH AND CEMETERY</Building_Name>
    <Address>2107 Goodrich Avenue</Address>
    <Ownership>NON-PROFIT</Ownership>
    <Date_Built>1860</Date_Built>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Longitude>-97.744671</Longitude>
    <Latitude>30.266270</Latitude>
    <Building_Name>DAVIS (NELSON) WAREHOUSE</Building_Name>
    <Address>107 West 4th  Street</Address>
    <Ownership>PRIVATE</Ownership>
    <Date_Built>1905</Date_Built>
</Row>
</Root>
```

I have a demo setup but somehow when i try to run the index file it won't show markers on the map.It would give me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of null

Could anyone please help. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you have mentioned indicates that the "xmlDoc" variable is null and you are trying to access the "documentElement" property of this null variable. 
  Due to the error the javascript code following this line won't execute due to which you won't see any markers on the map.

Please make sure the you are able to load the xml file correctly. That should solve your problem. Do let me know if it works out.

I'd also like to recommend that you switch to Google Map v3 as the Google Map v2 code that you have used in your example has been deprecated as mentioned in the following link.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/

> Note: The Google Maps JavaScript API Version 2 was officially deprecated on May 19, 2010. The original deprecation period has been extended from May 19, 2013 until November 19, 2013. As of this date, all applications requesting v2 will be served a special, wrapped version of the v3 API instead. We expect this wrapped version of the API will work for most simple maps, but we strongly encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps JavaScript API before this date.